# Guava Cache that does not cache

Tags: java, caching, guava

Is it possible to build/configure a [Cache](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html), which does not Cache at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.   `CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(0)` will do the job.

Comment: Yes or maximumWeight(0)